# Specific volume of an air parcel

Tags: physics

So I have an unsaturated air parcel in the atmosphere that ascends adiabatically from the $1000$ mb level to the $700$ mb level with its initial temperature being $10$ degrees Celsius.

I have to find the initial specific volume in $m^3/kg$.

I know that the specific volume formula is $v=1/ρ$ and that the equation of the state of an ideal gas can be written as $p=ρRT$ where $R$ is $8.3143$ $J/mol∗kg$

So I have $1000=ρ(8.3143)(273.15+10)$ and solve then for $ρ$ and then get $0.42477$ and plug that for $v=1/0.42477$ and get $2.354$ $m^3/kg$ as the initial specific volume... Am I doing this right? Thanks.

***I don't know where to ask this question. I tried the physics stack exchange but they deemed it off-topic of their website...***

Comment: "I don't know where to ask this question. I tried the physics stack exchange but they deemed it off-topic of their website..."

Those scumbags! Maybe try Chemsitry.SE if this is closed as off topic?